# "In which" etymology

Tags: history, questions

Why do we say "In which" in many formal essays and documents? I never understood this. The definition for which on Merriam Webster is "being what one or ones out of a group". Why is it that we have adapted to using the word 'which' outside of interrogative sentences?

Comment: Because _which_ is used as [a relative pronoun](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/162609/15299) at least as often as it is used as an interrogative pronoun. As for _in which_ it's formal language and helps mark the style. It's not much used in speech, which means it's not very important. Other prepositions occur, though; the technical term in syntax is "Pied-Piping".

Comment: We  haven't "adapted" to using "'which' outside of interrogative sentences."  Both the relative and interrogative uses come to us from Old English.  Which is to say that the dual usage is very old, over a thousand years, going back to the origins of language.

Comment: In older (Victorian?) era novels it was common for the chapters instead of having titles to have a short synopsis beginning with "in which...".  For example, chapter 3 might be the chapter "**in which** Johnny discovers his long-lost aunt". This fits your definition well, since we are describing what makes this chapter unique out of the group of all the chapters in the book. When you see this construction in contemporary writing, its usually an allusion to this old-fashioned way of introducing book chapters.

Comment: If Merriam Webster could not make it clear to you that "which" is used in questions and in relative clauses, you should use other dictionaries too. Perhaps a grammar wouldn't be bad.

Comment: Can you give an example of a sentence where "in which" is used in they way that you are asking about?

Comment: @sumelic 
In which year will the Supreme Court have nine justices again - this or next? We're currently awaiting a nomination in which the stakes are quite high.
https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/monkey-cage/wp/2016/02/25/when-was-the-last-supreme-court-nomination-in-which-stakes-were-this-high-maybe-never/

Comment: @JoshB: I was asking coder guy for an example. The example you give is an interrogative sentence, but coder guy said he had seen it used "in many formal essays and documents" "outside of interrogative sentences." I'd assume he meant something like "the house in which I live" but without a concrete example it's harder to answer his question.

Comment: The second sentence in my last comment using 'in which' is not an interrogative; I was trying to change the recent newspaper headline I noticed, which is linked, into a statement rather than a question.

Comment: Without some examples your question is invalid.  (I can't believe it wasn't closed two years ago.)

Answer (score 2):

Why do we say "In which"...?

...because "in which" is very much a part of written and spoken English, whether formal or informal.  It is simply a **prepositional phrase** composed of the preposition "in" and the relative pronoun "which."  It can be used to mean "where" or "that."  Therefore, it can be replaced by the latter two.  If you are not comfortable using "in which" try replacing it with *where* or *that*, whichever is applicable.

Examples:

- This is the room 'in which' the supplies were stocked.
- This is the room **where in** the supplies were stocked.
- The town 'in which' I spent my childhood years is now urbanized.
- The town **where** I spent my childhood years **in** is now urbanized. [Notice the **in** after 'years'.]
- The PC 'in which' the virus was discovered has been transferred to
  the stock room.
- The PC **that** the virus was discovered **in** has been transferred to
  the stock room. [Notice the "in" after 'discovered'.]
- The subject 'in which' I got the highest score is Math.
- The subject **that** I got the highest score **in** is Math. [Notice the "in" after 'score'.]

Well, that's the *compromise*.  You will have to use and place **in** in appropriate part of the sentence if you opt to use **where** and **that** instead of 'in which'.

+++

Why is it that we have adapted to using the word 'which' outside of interrogative sentences?

The relative pronoun 'which' is not only for *interrogative sentences*.  It is also used in *statements* as in the following ways:

- I shopped at the store **which** sells trendy dresses and shoes.
- The owner of the car **which** hit our van did not appear during the mediation.