# Use of "in which"

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions, word-order, pied-piping

In the following, does 'in which' sound right?

> Therefore, some design patterns will be implemented programmatically
>   during the writing of this thesis, in order to analyze and to compare.
>   Swift is the programming language ***in which*** the patterns are
>   implemented, and iOS is the name of the Apple’s mobile operating
>   system (platform).

Comment: Best previous answer possibly at [In which etymology](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/275358/in-which-etymology), though there are better candidates for duplicates.

Comment: Sounds ok. Depends on how formal you're trying to sound. Could have been worded "The patterns are implemented with the Swift programming language" but "Swift is the programming language in which the patterns are implemented" gives it that pretentious sound college professors love.

Comment: I suspect that this use is to avoid having a preposition at the end of a clause (that old bugaboo, which never was a proscription): *Swift is the programming language that the patterns are implemented in*. But it sounds alright as is.

Comment: Why wouldn't you simply say that it's πthe programming language the patterns are implemented in”?  Pied piping always leads to ugly things nobody actually says.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's grammatically correct, but it would seem more natural to say "Swift is the programming language that is used to implement the patterns..."