# What part of speech is the word "how" in this sentence?

Tags: parts-of-speech

In the sentence:

> My philosophy professor demonstrated not only how to reason persuasively but also how to avoid logical fallacies.

What part of speech is the word *how*?

Comment: What part of speech in what sense?  Do you want to know which meaning of the word "how" is being used here?

Comment: In *How are you?* *how* is an interrogative pronoun. In *She explained how to complete the form*, *how* is a relative pronoun. *How* is no different in this respect to *who, which, and where*. At least that's my understanding from when I last studied these things at school about 60 years ago! I doubt it has changed since.

Comment: @WS2 What is the relative clause in your example? I can't see a noun that is being modified.

Comment: @BillJ Relative clause - *to complete the form*, I think!

Comment: This is something which the Dictionary can answer.  **how**   1
haʊ /  ***adverb***  1.  in what way or manner; by what means.
"how does it work?"
2.  used to ask about the condition or quality of something.
"how was your holiday?" Here it is used a a conjunction to introduce the indirect Question.

Comment: @Hugh So does that mean *who, where* and *when* are adverbs? What happened to interrogative pronouns?

Comment: Who, whom, what, which, whose. these are pronouns. I think how, when, where, why, whether are usually called 'interrogatives.'  They act as modifiers of the verb, or of the phrase, or adjectives; so that ought to signal adverb But all are used to introduce indirect questions,

Comment: One response on ELU calls it a subordinating conjunction.  But a full discussion is given here ***A relative adverb or a conjunction or both?***   http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/162576/a-relative-adverb-or-a-conjunction-or-both/162609#162609

Comment: You can call "how" interrogative pronoun (so in grammars) or simply question word.

Answer (score 3):

Both the *how*s there are adverbs that premodify the respective to-infinitive clauses. The first how premodifies *to reason persuasively*, and the second *to avoid logical fallacies*.

The fact that both *how to reason persuasively* and *how to avoid logical fallacies* are complements of the verb *demonstrated* doesn't change the part of speech of *how* at all, because *how* itself is not a complement of the verb. Only those clauses are.

Answer (score 0):

It is Adverb and the mood is interrogative

Comment: Welcome to English.SE! Could you perhaps elaborate a little on this answer?