# Relative pronoun vs. relative adverb

Tags: grammar, adverbs, relative-clauses, relative-pronouns

> [1] *"That picture was taken in the park **where I used to play**."* 
>   (Here, **'where'** is an relative adverb.
>
> [2] *"I remember the day **when we first met**."* 
>   (Here, **'when'** is an relative adverb.)

Source : 
https://www.ef.com/ca/english-resources/english-grammar/relative-adverbs/

> [3] *"Grandma remembers a time **when radio shows were popular**."* 
>   (Here, **'when'** is a relative pronoun.)
>
> [4] *"I want to visit the island **where my grandma was born**."*
>   (Here, **'where'** is a relative pronoun.)

Source : 
https://grammar.yourdictionary.com/parts-of-speech/pronouns/relative-pronoun.html

It seems to be confusing that "when" and "where" are relative adverbs in sentence [1] & [2] while they're relative pronouns in sentence [3] and [4].

How can we determine whether **"when"** and **"where"** are *relativel pronouns* or *relative adverbs*?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why: a relative adverb, a conjunction ... or both?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/162576/why-a-relative-adverb-a-conjunction-or-both) John Lawler looks at all the 'Wh-words'.

Comment: "When" and "where" are certainly not pronouns -- that would be an impossible analysis. Traditional grammar classifies them as adverbs, which I think is good enough for your purposes. The most important thing is that "where" and "when" function in the relative clause as adjuncts of place or time respectively, hence their classification as adverbs.

Comment: Okay, but it means the definition given by yourdictionary.com is wrong. I also think that they're not relative pronouns; they are relative adverbs.

Comment: Yes, it is mistaken in saying that sometimes the relative adverbs "where" and "when" can also be used as relative pronouns -- that is a ridiculous  claim. Adverb and pronoun are distinct word classes -- a word cannot belong to both at the same time in any given phrase or clause.

Comment: So, in _That picture was taken in the park where I used to play_, the word "where" is an adverb functioning as an adjunct of place. The meaning is "That picture was taken in park x"; I used to play in x". The interpretation is like that of a PP [link](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/where), which explains why one acclaimed modern grammar classifies "where" as a preposition.

Comment: One doesn't change the properties or affordances of a word class by changing its name. The _wh_-words all have their own uses, which sprawl all over the official definitions of link labels. Few things are less useful or more irritating than arguing over terminology; it's arbitrary and it's not data.

Comment: @JohnLawler I don't understand how you could discuss grammar without introducing terminology, though.

Comment: Of course you need to correctly identify word classes (parts of speech), especially as you would have to use them as labels in a tree diagram. The website you provided a link to is undoubtedly mistaken: the _wh_ words you cite are all adverbs for your purposes, and their function is that of adjunct of place / time.